# Call REST Service from Win32 application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, curl, https

I have an Win32 application which runs on the Windows server (2003 & later).  My application has to call a REST service to POST some JSON data.

How can I proceed with implementation? Which library or SDK should I use to call REST service from C++ application.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using modern C++11 **Casablanca REST API** developed by Microsoft. This API is now included into Visual Studio installation package. You can also use **WinHTTP** API which is kind of legacy stuff. There is also MFC/ATL implementation called **ATL Server** that does include HTTP Client classes.

Comment: We don't suggest off site resources here.

Comment: Sorry, did not know that. It is hard to answer the question without specifying external resources. I can remove URLs from answer if needed.

Comment: The question is off-topic and should be removed. There's no way to give an answer that's not off-topic in turn. Thus I'd recommend to delete your answer.

Comment: I did remove URLs to external resources as you've suggested. But I'd like to help santhosh to choose the right direction. I believe that my answer is valuable.

Comment: I didn't suggest to remove the URLs. You may want to read my comment again. See point 4. of the off-topic reasons for questions here please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks  @AndrewKomiagin .. Can I use Casablanca REST API in VS2010?

Comment: I'm not sure, probably not. As far as I know VS2010 does not support C++11 standard.